# How to run a simulation using three different vectors?

Tags: r, simulation

I am currently trying to create a simulation using three different vector for phi, alpha, and beta.

The following is the code I have thus far:

```
install.packages("FAdist")

library(FAdist) ## used to calculate a shifted gamma distribution

lamada = 1.000163867

phi = seq(0.01,0.21,0.01)
power = c(1:8) 
alpha = 10^power

beta = seq(0.004,1,0.002)   
n = 10
N=n+5


simu = function(n, phi, lamada, alpha, beta){

    M = rpois(N,lambda= -beta*log(phi))  
    g1=0
    phihat=0

    for(k in 1:100){
        x0 = rgamma3(n=1, shape=alpha, scale=beta, thres=lamada)
        epsil = 0


        for(i in 1:N){
            if(M[i]!=0){
                Yj = rexp(M[i],rate=alpha)
                Uj = runif(M[i], 0, 1)
                eta = sum(Yj^Uj)
            } else{eta=0}
            epsil[i] = lamada*(1-phi)+eta
        }
        x=0
        x[1] = phi*x0+epsil[1] #first observation

        for(i in 2:N){
            x[i] = phi*x[i-1]+epsil[i]
        }

        x= x[6:N]

        phihat[k] = acf(x)$acf[2]
        phihat[k] = (phihat[k]*n+1)/(n-4)

        g1[k] = (n/((n-1)*(n-2)*var(x)^(3/2)))*sum((x-mean(x))^3)
    }

    phihatbar = mean(phihat)
    g1bar = mean(g1)

    gamma = 2/sqrt(beta)
    newlist = list("phihatbar"= phihatbar, "g1bar"=g1bar, "gamma"=gamma)
    return(newlist)
}
```

As you can see by my function, I am trying to print out the values of phihatbar, g1bar, and gamma. Instead of using for loops, I am trying to use the function sapply() for my simulation calculations.

If I fixed both beta and phi, I can calculate the values with the alpha vector with the following line of code:

```
sapply(alpha, simu, n=n, phi=phi, lamada=lamada, beta=beta)
```

But how can I print the values of phihatbar, g1bar, and gamma, by having alpha, phi, and beta to be vectors? I have tried to use the sapply function again, but I am receiving an error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close since this is a question about programming, not about statistics.  This question is better off being migrated to stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to use your function `simu` over many values of `alpha`, `phi`, and `beta`.

I wont go through your code right now, but I suggest you use `pmap` or `map2` from the `purrr` package. It basically executes a function over a set of equally length lists, in "parallel". It runs the function with the first element of each argument, the with the second, and so on.

The following exemple from the `purr::pmap` documentation:

```
x <- list(1, 10, 100)
y <- list(1, 2, 3)
z <- list(5, 50, 500)
pmap(list(x, y, z), sum)
```

Results in a list, such that:

```
[[1]]
[1] 7

[[2]]
[1] 62

[[3]]
[1] 603
```

**Disclaimer**: `purrr`'s functions are supposed to be replacements of a bunch of `base-r` functions, so I am sure that you can find a solution without using a different package. But I don't know `base-r` :D